# Is there anyway you can remove inside table rows borders in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]In Apache POI you can remove all borders from a table, however I do not want to remove all borders, I just want to remove borders of the inside rows of a table, is it possible? Does Apache POI offer a way to do this?

I created the following method to create a table. What I need is to remove top and bottom borders from the second column.

```
public void theTable(XWPFDocument doc) {

    XWPFTable t = doc.createTable(2,3);

    t.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth("5000");
    t.getRow(0).getCell(1).setWidth("500");
    t.getRow(0).getCell(2).setWidth("5000");

}
```

I have the following that does not meet my goal as it targets the whole table not specifically column 2:

```
    t.removeBorders();
    t.removeBottomBorder();
    t.removeInsideHBorder();
    t.removeInsideVBorder();
    t.removeLeftBorder();
    t.removeRightBorder();
    t.removeTopBorder();
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Hi Axel I just added the method that creates the table, what I am having issues is targeting column 2 borders specifically.

Comment: You should at least mention in your questions what part of `apache poi` is in question. If one talks about the term "table" in context of `apache poi` without any further context, most people will think it is about `Excel`. But of course a code sample removes all doubts. So no question should be without code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to current Apache POI 4.1.2, the `XWPFTableCell` lacks methods for border setting. But table cells of a `Word` table may have own border settings. So those methods should be added in further versions.

Until then, we could provide a own method to do this using the underlying `ooxml-schemas` classes.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class CreateWordTableCellBorders {

 private enum Border { LEFT, TOP, BOTTOM, RIGHT }

 static void setTableCellBorder(XWPFTableCell cell, Border border, STBorder.Enum type) {
  CTTc tc = cell.getCTTc();
  CTTcPr tcPr = tc.getTcPr(); if (tcPr == null) tcPr = tc.addNewTcPr();
  CTTcBorders tcBorders = tcPr.getTcBorders(); if (tcBorders == null) tcBorders = tcPr.addNewTcBorders();
  if (border == Border.LEFT) {
   CTBorder left = tcBorders.getLeft(); if(left == null) left = tcBorders.addNewLeft();
   left.setVal(type);
  } else if (border == Border.TOP) {
   CTBorder top = tcBorders.getTop(); if(top == null) top = tcBorders.addNewTop();
   top.setVal(type);
  } else if (border == Border.BOTTOM) {
   CTBorder bottom = tcBorders.getBottom(); if(bottom == null) bottom = tcBorders.addNewBottom();
   bottom.setVal(type);
  } else if (border == Border.RIGHT) {
   CTBorder right = tcBorders.getRight(); if(right == null) right = tcBorders.addNewRight();
   right.setVal(type);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  //create the table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(2,3);

  //set column widths and table cell borders
  for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
   row.getCell(0).setWidth("5000");
   row.getCell(1).setWidth("500");
   setTableCellBorder(row.getCell(1), Border.TOP, STBorder.NIL);
   setTableCellBorder(row.getCell(1), Border.BOTTOM, STBorder.NIL);
   row.getCell(2).setWidth("5000");
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableCellBorders.docx"); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, it's exactly what I was looking for. I am sure this answers a lot of people's questions when it comes to table row borders in java apache-poi.